# javascript get element's tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags

Lets say this is my HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
<input id="goo" value="text" />
<span id="boo">
</span>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to determine what tag belongs to a html element.

Example element with id "foo" = `div`, "goo" = `input`, "boo" = `span` ...

So something like this:

```
function getTag (id) {
   var element = document.getElementById(id);
   return element.tag;
}
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

[**HTMLElement.tagName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName)

```js
const element = document.getElementById('myImgElement');
console.log('Tag name: ' + element.tagName);
// Tag name: IMG
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" id="myImgElement" alt="">
```

**NOTE**: It returns tags in capitals. E.g. `<img />` will return `IMG`.

Comment: note that this returns the capitalized name, ie `BUTTON` or `INPUT`, regardless of your actual HTML