# How to check what an element is if we only know its ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If we only know the ID of an element, is it possible to check using javascript or jQuery what kind of an element it is, whether its textarea, div, span or something else?

Comment: the answer should be here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539419/javascript-get-elements-tag]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can javascript determine the type of an html element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254302/how-can-javascript-determine-the-type-of-an-html-element)

Comment: Is this meant for a third-party library, an extension or something? For a custom piece of JavaScript that belongs to a page, formally you are supposed to already know what element it is. That's what IDs are for: to positively identify an element. So when you don't know what it is, there's something fundamentally wrong with our design!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using `jQuery`:

```
$("#someid").prop("tagName");
```

By using `JavaScript`:

```
document.getElementById("someid").tagName;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('#id').nodeName
```